# Dell XPS m1210 LCD Backlight does not want to stay on at first

Tags: laptop, lcd, dell-xps, backlight

I have a Dell XPS m1210 that I've been using for almost 6 years now.  Recently the LCD screen back light would turn on for a few seconds, then shut off until I closed the screen and opened it up again.  Every time I would open it up the light would come on, then shut off.  This would happen for the first few minutes I had the laptop on until whatever the problem component is would warm up and the light stays on.

What would be the most likely component here that's starting to fail?

Comment: Oh, this laptop. I have one, and the graphics card will completely die (rendering the screen blank and requiring a restart) if it hasn't warmed up yet. Nvidia actually had a recall of the GPUs a while back; that might be the issue (though mine was replaced and has the same issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some additional reading on the problem, I fixed it by replacing the power inverter board.  Ruling out all other issues such as control signals, bad mobo, and wiring, the inverter was the first most likely component to have failed.

Answer (score 0):

Too many reasons here, screen problem, connector problem between the keyboard and the display, bad graphics board, bad connectors, bad motherboard.  Not much we can eliminate here via textual responses.

Maybe its time for a new laptop.  6 years is beyond the standard time of 3-5 years for the general usefulness of system hardware.